# shell script to run multiple or selective python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to create a shell script say job.sh that stores a collection of the python scripts. How can I run one or multiple selected scripts?

This is what I hope to have in job.sh

```
jobaias1:

python /path_to_script/script1.py $1 $2

jobaias2:

python /path_to_script/script2.py $1 $2
```

Then in terminal:

```
./job.sh jobalias1 arg1 arg2
```

or

```
./job.sh jobalias2 arg1 arg2
```

or

```
./job.sh jobalias1&&jobalias2
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146

Comment: Just make a `bash` `alias` https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/